# When using a LINQ Where clause on a Dictionary, how can I return a dictionary of the same type?

Tags: c#, linq, optimization

I'm currently using the following code to achieve this, but is seems there should be something better...  suggestions?  It just seems to me there should be a way to skip the foreach...

```
Dictionary<string,string> getValidIds(Dictionary<string,string> SalesPersons,List<string> ids)
{
    Dictionary<string,string> o = new Dictionary<string,string>();
    var ie = SalesPersons.Where<KeyValuePair<string, string>>(t => ids.Contains(t.Key));
    foreach (var i in ie)
    {
        o.Add(i.Key, i.Value);
    }
    return o;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems to be a lot of fussing about looking things up in the List.  If the list only contains a few elements, then no big deal.  If the List contains thousands of elements, you're going to want O(1) lookups into it.  HashSet can provide this.

```
Dictionary<string, string> getValidIds(
  Dictionary<string, string> SalesPersons,
  List<string> ids
)
{
  HashSet<string> idsFast = new HashSet<string>(ids);
  Dictionary<string, string> result = SalesPersons
    .Where(kvp => idsFast.Contains(kvp.Key))
    .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value)
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Pretty sure you could just call ToDictionary on the result of the Where call:

```
Dictionary<string, string> GetValidIds(Dictionary<string, string> salesPersons,
    IList<string> ids)
{
    return salesPersons
        .Where(p => ids.Contains(p.Key))
        .ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => p.Value);
}
```

Comment: +1, Marc, although I think if you're worried about perf with this sort of thing you've got way too much in memory as it is! :)

Comment: @Matt... well, maybe - but there is a point where O(1)/O(N*log(N)) *isn't* unreasonable, but O(N^2) *is* a problem - whether that is 1k, 10k or 100k is up to the specific process, of course.

Answer (score 7):

Interestingly, if you enumerate over the dictionary (length N) *first* and check the list (length M) for inclusion, then you get O(NM) performance.

You could build a `HashSet<>` of the ids, but that seems redundant since we already have a (pre-hashed) dictionary available.

I would instead iterate over the ids first; since dictionary lookup (by key) is O(1), this gives O(M) performance - this might, however, mean that you don't use LINQ (since `TryGetValue` won't love LINQ (and introducing a tuple is too much like hard work)...

```
    Dictionary<string, string> getValidIds(
            IDictionary<string, string> salesPersons,
            IEnumerable<string> ids) {
        var result = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        string value;
        foreach (string key in ids) {
            if (salesPersons.TryGetValue(key, out value)) {
                result.Add(key, value);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

It doesn't overly concern me that this is more lines than the LINQ version; it removes an O(N) of complexity...

---

Edit; the following *might* work (I haven't tested it), but I think it is an abuse of LINQ, and certainly won't scale to PLINQ etc... use with extreme caution!! I also believe the `foreach` approach simply has fewer overheads, so will be quicker... anyway:

```
    Dictionary<string, string> getValidIds(
        IDictionary<string, string> salesPersons,
        IEnumerable<string> ids)
    {
        string value = null;
        return  (from key in ids
                where salesPersons.TryGetValue(key, out value) // HACK: v. dodgy
                select new { key, value })
                .ToDictionary(x=>x.key, x=>x.value);
    }
```